# how to override toString() method in android service?

Tags: java, android, tostring

I was trying to override the toString() function of a service. I have a service and I am using another app to access the toString(). However the output is not as expected, I suspect that the overriding of toString() has failed ! Can anyone help ? Thanks

```
///////////////toString Function in the service !///////////////

public String toString() {
   return "Hello World";
}

//////////how I am calling the overridden function !////////////////////

ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rs = am.getRunningServices(50);

for (int i=0; i<rs.size(); i++) {
    ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo rsi = rs.get(i);
    Log.i("Hello",rsi.getClass().toString());
    Log.i("Service", "Process " + rsi.process + " with component " + 
            rsi.service.getClassName());
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've wrote...that'll be helpfull.  and btw, it's `Overriding` not `overloading`, its 2 different things.

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake. I am attaching the code I used for toString() and the way I am calling it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You expect to have `rsi.getClass().toString()` return "Hello World" right?
It doesn't work as expected above, because you call another `toString` method in another object. You call this function: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#toString()

Problem here is, that `RunningServiceInfo` only tells you about what Service is running. It doesn't actually give you the object of your service.

Now how can you get it correct? Depends on what you want to do exactly.

But the nicest way to access your service out of another application is to bind to it.
If your Service is in the same app, you can follow this tutorial:
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iii-android-services/

How to do that out of another application:
[how to bind a remote service that is installed on my android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645783)